# java opencv - remove background from image

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-editing

I am very new to Opencv and have spent hours and hours to find a solution for my issue but I have not been able to resolve it. I have a image basically a X-ray that shows the screw/ nut/ or any external object installed in person's body. I want to be able to read the image, remove all the background noise and just have a clean image so that I can compare it to set of image within a database. 
I have tried applying Threshold and some other filters but not able to remove background from the image.

Stackoverflow did not let me attach the image as I am a new user and does not have 10 reputation.
Any help would be appreciated as i am stuck and cannot proceed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Ravi

Comment: Perhaps a background substraction tutorial can help: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html

Comment: Thanks Dan. I looked at the tutorial for background subtraction. I my case I just have a static single image (1 frame) and cannot use the method from the tutorial. Is there any other way to remove the background from static image??